# Simple node analysis

Tags: transfer-function, laplace-transform

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXyvtf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I calculated the transfer function 
 $$\frac{I_L}{In}=\frac{R_1R_2}{s^2L^2+sL(R_1+R_2)}$$

starting from the node analysis at the nodes V1 and V2, so:
$$\frac{V_1}{R_1}+\frac{V_1}{Ls}-\frac{V_2}{Ls}=In $$
$$-\frac{V_1}{Ls}+\frac{V_2}{Ls}+\frac{V_2}{R_2}=0$$

Because I obtain a second order system, this seems quite wrong.

Have I consider the admittances in the node analysis? So:
$$\frac{V_1}{G_1}+V_1Ls-V_2Ls=In$$
$$-V_1Ls+V_2Ls\frac{V_2}{G_2}=0$$
In this case I obtain a more likely:
$$\frac{I_L}{In}=\frac{1}{sL(R_1+R_2)+R_1R_2}$$

But I'am not sure about the node analysis.

What do you think is the correct solution?

Note: In both cases I consider $$I_L=\frac{V_2}{Ls}$$

Comment: inspection of the transfer function at dc (s at zero) tells you it is wrong.

Comment: @Andy aka: Thanks for the advice. I think that I found the problem, it's just that I(L) must be equal to (V1-V2)/Ls. At least, I think :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest path to the transfer function is to use current division which gives you the answer by inspection:

$$I_L = I_n \frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2 + sL} $$

Also, the final formula in your question is incorrect; the voltage across the inductor is not \$V_2\$

Comment: Indeed Alfred, that's the solution that I was looking for :D I found that in two different ways: Thevenin and simply calculate I as (V1-V2)/Ls with the first system. Thanks.